# Delete data in laravel with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to delete data with ajax in laravel 5.8

this is my table in role view

```
        <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Role User</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($roles as $role)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $role->nama }}</td>
                <td>

                    <button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#modal-danger" data-id="{{ $role->id }}">
                        <i class='fa fa-trash'>&nbsp</i> Delete
                    </button>

                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

this is my modal

```
<div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="modal-danger">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure ?</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" id="delete_ok" name="delete_ok">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my javascript function

```
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $('#modal-danger').show();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $('#delete_ok').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "roleuser/" + id,
            type: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(id);
                $('#modal-danger').hide();
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

this is my route and controller

```
 Route::resource('roleuser', 'RoleUserController');

    public function destroy(RoleUser $id)
{
    $roleuser = RoleUser::find($id);
    $roleuser->deleted_at = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time());
    $roleuser->save();

    return redirect()->route('roleuser.index')->with('alert-success', 'Deleted User Role successfully !');
}
```

i am already add meta tag in master view

```
<meta name="csrf-token" id="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

when i check : php artisan route:list . like this :

```
|        | DELETE    | roleuser/{roleuser}                                                    | roleuser.destroy                        | App\Http\Controllers\RoleUserController@destroy                                  | web,auth     |
```

but when i try to delete data, in console show id but still not go to my controller ...
can somebody help ?? whats wrong in my code ?

thankyouu :)

Comment: I think your route have issue. May be like `roleuser/{id}`

Comment: @502_Geek but when i check my route:list .. i can look my route deleted sir

Comment: Then, you may need to this `RoleUserController@destroy`

Comment: try with `method: 'delete',` instead `type: "DELETE",` in your ajax call

Comment: @502_Geek if add this, i have double method delete in route:list sir .. and try but still nothing

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ still nothing sir

Comment: How do you know it doesn't reach the controller? Did you try return something like `return 'ok';`. ( i'think `return redirect()` will not work with ajax ). Also you can try changing the params to `function destroy(RoleUser $roleuser) { $roleuser->deleted_at = ... }` (note you'll no longer need `$roleuser = RoleUser::find($id);`)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ because, in my controller i add "dd($id)" but i am not catch that

Comment: replace `url: "roleuser/" + id,` to `url: "/roleuser/"+ id`